# Problems adding chapters - FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a problem and I need help.
I have read each post on the subject, but I have no solution, it turns out that when trying to add chapters to a video they are written, but they erase or overwrite the subtitles, is there a way to add the chapters without overwriting and keeping the information?

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 03:01:21.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 937 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 801 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2: Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the basic command:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -f ffmetadata -i input.chap -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s -map_metadata 1 -map_chapters 1 -c copy OUTPUT
```

`-map 0:v`, `-map 0:a` and `-map 0:s` to keep the video+audio+subtitles streams of the INPUT file
`-map_metadata 1` to include the metadata of the input.chap file to output
`-map_chapters 1` to include the chapters of the input.chap file to output
`-c copy` for stream copy all streams